# Can I say "Hiking the Lighthouse/Mountain/Jones Path"?

Tags: prepositions, present-participles

If there is a path called the Lighthouse Path (somewhere at the coast) or Mountain Path or Jones Path (named after somebody who identified it) and I want to hike it, is it correct to say "Hiking the Lighthouse/Mountain/Jones Path" ? Or should there be a preposition?

As far as I know, if it was a trail, I can say "Hiking the Lighthouse/Mountain/Jones trail". Is it correct?

Additional question: for the Jones case, is there 'the Jones path/trail' or just 'Jones path/trail' ?

Comment: The short answer is yes. And the *the* is typically necessary. But note that use of *the* can vary - witness the way southern Californians refer to highways: *the 405* versus the way northern Californians refer to them: *405*, *Interstate 405*, or *highway 405*. I'd say find out how the locals refer to *Jones Path* or whatever, and do likewise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are completing the entire trail, no preposition is necessary for most verbs related to travel or transportation. The route or journey is used as an [adverb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491), indicating the place where the travel is occurring. This is common with named routes—

- *We will take turns driving [Pacific Coast Highway](http://alyssapadgett.com/drive-pacific-coast-highway/).*
- *The new job makes him fly the [Kangaroo Route](http://andc.anu.edu.au/sites/default/files/WotM%20July%20kangaroo%20route%202014.pdf) monthly.*
- *She had tramped the entire [Milford Track](http://www.csmonitor.com/1986/0711/qmilf.html) with only one shoelace.*
- *April is a good time to ride the [Tail of the Dragon](http://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/motorcycles/the-great-roads-tail-of-the-dragon-15695960)*

— but you can also use it with arbitrarily defined trips—

- *I was biking the five miles from Westwood to Santa Monica every morning.*
- *They drove the long way home, to take in the view.*
- *He rode the seven stops from Hartsfield to Five Points without incident.*

If you are not hiking the entire path, however, I would likely include a preposition such as *on* or *along*. If the path is more important than the mode of transport, you can use *take* or *follow*:

- *We drove on [Autoroute 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_Autoroute_20) most of the way, but took the Pierre Laporte Bridge just to say we'd been on it.*
- *The tour follows the Mormon Trail from Fort Bridger to Big Mountain.*

As to whether the trail name takes the definite article, the short answer is "usually yes" when referring to a route but not when referring to a road— but as always with articles, [the matter is complicated](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161504). I can't think of any U.S. hiking/equestrian/biking [trail/path/track](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159307) that is not referred to without the article off the top of my head, but there are always exceptions.

Comment: Very helpful. If there are several trails named after one person, is it ok to use an indefinite article, ie "Walking a Jones trail" ?

Comment: @user155002 *A Jones trail* would normally be interpreted as referring to one of a type of or set of trails. To use it to indicate unrelated trails of the same name is to underscore a coincidence, or irony, or other unusual circumstance. *I'm planning to trek the [John Muir Trail](http://www.pcta.org/discover-the-trail/john-muir-trail/) this spring. It'll take about 5 months. / That's funny, I'm riding a [John Muir Trail](http://www.travelwisconsin.com/mountain-biking/john-muir-trails-204374) too, but I'll finish in one day. Granted, mine is a little flatter.*